# JBWEB003073: Error finishing response: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, web-services, nullpointerexception, jboss-eap-6

I am using jboss EAP 6.3 to deploy a webservice using @WebService annotation and a client that open concurrent threads to request the same method from that web service, and each thread has it is own instance of webservice, but some times the server is produce an exception with the following message:

```
JBWEB001018: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing: java.lang.NullPointerException  at

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.setValue(MimeHeaders.java:381) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1558) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:977) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:190) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:390) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:358) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:324) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.finishResponse(Response.java:487) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:375) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]

14:24:38,112 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11] (http-/193.16.1.68:8330-25) JBWEB003073: Error finishing response: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.setValue(MimeHeaders.java:381) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1558) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:977) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:188) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:347) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest(Http11Processor.java:937) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:883) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
```

Any advise?

Best regards,
Abdulghaffar

Comment: Is this the entirety of the stacktrace?

Comment: Yes it is the entirety of the stack trace. and this exception is produced for each web service request  failure.